# I can't get menu navigation to go in the correct order

Tags: c#, menu, navigation

I'm writing a C# Windows program. I put a MenuStrip at the top of the main form, with entries from left-to-right as:

File      Topic 1       Topic 2    Window     Help

Click on any of them and another strip drops-down.

When I select Alt-F, the File menu will drop down. When I press the Right Arrow, I expect to move over to the "Topic 1" menu. Hit it again, I expect to go to "Topic 2", then Window, then Help, then back to File. If I hit the Left Arrows, I expect tpo go from File to Help to Window to "Topic 2" to "Topic 1", then back to File again.

For some reason, my program is selecting the menus in the opposite direction I'd expect. If I'm on File and I press Right-Arrow, I get put on Help, not "Topic 1". I don't see a TabIndex on the menus. Any idea what this might be from?

Comment: Agreed, it is weird. No wonder I couldn't find it in my searches. I will try changing the MenuStrip to a MainMenu, will let you know...thanks!

Comment: Hold on now...I don't see a MainMenu object in the toolbox...???

Comment: Oh yeah, it's in the background list of toolbox controls. I ended up switching and it works now. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug in `MenuStrip`. Had to change to `MainMenu`, which is supposed to be unsupported.